# How to decode bytearray column in dataframe using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[My CSV file containing Sales data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CUwypcwJgci_sBpOLh6XsWKN5oX7ZJRo/view?usp=sharing)

I have fetching data from mysql database in which service-price and ticket price column which is in data 2,000, 34,688 etc in that column but when I converted it in CSV or in data-frame then I got service-price and ticket-price column in this format " bytearray(b'6,700\xe5\x86\x86')" or "b'45,664,467,635\xe5\x86\x86'" etc in that column.

How to decode that service-price and ticket_price column in actual format so that I can apply preprocessing on it to predict sales?

I am using python3.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply decode the byte string to `utf` (or the encoding you're using) using the below:

```
example_byte_string = b'this is a byte string'
example_utf8_string = example_byte_string.decode("utf-8")
```

or you could simply use `str(b'bytes')` - The default encoding is `utf-8` as shown in the definition below:

```
class str(object=b'', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is used to decode only one byte or bytearray but I want  to decode whole one column which is in bytearray or byte format.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CUwypcwJgci_sBpOLh6XsWKN5oX7ZJRo/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: please google drive link to see salesjts1.csv dataset. for reference.

Comment: I have problem to decode in column "service_name", "service_price", "sale_price","ticket_price". This such column is in bytearray and bytes.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uYYWgy8OXvPWy0u5sA-J0gF8u-YRkTU6/view?usp=sharing